# Can't get virtual host working

Tags: 14.04, apache2, drupal

I have 3 drupal sites working on my local dev box Ubuntu 14.04. I had problems getting the second and third ones working and when they did it just seemed like luck. Those 3 kept me going for a long time but now I need a fourth and I can't get it working.

Here is my process for creating a site

1. Put drupal files in folder ~/workspace/sitedemo1
2. Create virtual host sitedemo1.conf (copy one of the working ones and then edit relevant details)
3. edit /etc/ports - enter "127.0.0.1 sitedemo1"
4. a2ensite sitedemo1
5. service apache2 reload

The result is that I get the 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page'
I'm pretty confused because the other 3 sites are working and I did the same thing.

**sitedemo1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias sitedemo1
    DocumentRoot /home/karl/workspace/sitedemo1
    <Directory "/home/karl/workspace/sitedemo1">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Above I mixed-up /etc/hosts and /etc/apache2/ports.conf. Here is the contents of both.

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
# original line: Listen 80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.2:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443    
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Ubuntu-05
127.0.0.1   drupal-8.localhost
127.0.0.1   drupal-7-site01.localhost
127.0.0.1   drupal-7-site02.localhost
127.0.0.1 sitedemo1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: I'm not sure about step 3. Did you edit /etc/apache2/ports.conf? could you post sitedemo1.conf and /etc/ports file?

Comment: @Letizia I added the additional information to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html):

> ServerName inheritance
>
> It is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in every name-based
>   virtual host.
>
> If a VirtualHost doesn't specify a ServerName, a server name will be
>   inherited from the base server configuration. If no server name was
>   specified globally, one is detected at startup through reverse DNS
>   resolution of the first listening address. In either case, this
>   inherited server name will influenced name-based virtual host
>   resolution, so it is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in
>   every name-based virtual host.

ServerName requires [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) try change sitedemo1 in sitedemo1.localhost in configuration file (/etc/hosts and sitedemo1.conf)

Add ServerAlias with:

```
   ServerName sitedemo1.localhost
```

Comment: I gave that a try. Changed ServerAlias to ServerName for all 4 sites I have. The first 3 are still working but sitedemo1 still goes to the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

Comment: ServerName requires [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) try change sitedemo1 in sitedemo1.localhost in configuration file (/etc/hosts and sitedemo1.conf) and if you want sitedemo1 add ServerAlias sitedemo1

Comment: Thank you! adding .localhost to the server name in sitedemo1.conf and in /etc/hosts did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I have been struggling with this issue for days, pretty sure that my vshosts were configured correclty, I have the same configuration in other apaches and never had to use the .localhost, actually I didn't even had to change my hosts file or anything, just added .localhost to what I had defined and... voila ...